# Jquery animation slowing down after clear queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loops

hope you can help with an animation issue in jQuery. I am using the following code to make an animated loop that I can start and stop, and can choose whether the element being animated is pulsing, or moving, as in an arrow:

```
//set the flashing pointer on or off
function flashPointer(state, time, el, style){
    switch(state){
        case "on":
            loopPointer(time, style, el);
        break;
        case "off":
            $(el).stop(true, false).fadeOut(100, function(){ 
                $(el).clearQueue();
            });
        break;
    }
```

}

```
//make a pointer graphic fade in and out
function loopPointer(time, style, el){
    switch(style){
        case "fade":
        $(el).fadeIn(time, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(time, function(){
                loopPointer(1000, "fade", el);
            }); 
        });
        break;

        case "move":
        $(el).fadeIn(time).animate({top:15}, time, function(){
            $(this).animate({top:0}, function(){
                loopPointer(1000, "move", el);
            }); 
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why if I start and stop the animation a bunch of times it gets progressively more slow?

Any other comments and points to improve are of course also welcome.

Thanks all ;)

Jamie

UPDATE

I am calling these functions like so:

```
flashPointer("on", 1000, "#pointer", "move");
flashPointer("off", 1000, "#pointer", "move");
flashPointer("on", 1000, "#pointer", "fade");
flashPointer("off", 1000, "#pointer", "fade");
```

I am calling the above function once to switch the fader on, for example, when the browser requests access to the user's geo location info, and calling again to switch it off once the required info / permission has been given.

Hope that helps explain what I am trying to do?

Thanks for your help!

Jamie

Comment: Looks to me that you've got binding issues and asynchronous issues colliding. How are you calling your functions?

Comment: Hi Stevo, thanks a lot for replying. I am calling with the followinn:

PRESSED ENTER TOO EARLY HERE!

Comment: the following:
    flashPointer("on", 1000, "#pointer", "move");
or
    flashPointer("off", 1000, "#pointer", "move");
or
    flashPointer("on", 1000, "#pointer", "fade");
or
    flashPointer("off", 1000, "#pointer", "fade");

thanks again for your help!

Jamie

NOTE: I can't seem to style the code in this reply ;(

Comment: Best to update the question with the code, then if someone else reads it they can see the information thus far. What I mean is - how are you binding the function calls to user action?

Comment: Cheers Stevo, I've updated it now, hope that helps?